# Rails pipeline not picking up environment variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having a problem with my GitLab pipeline which should run my Ruby on Rails tests. In my project I have the following `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
stages:
  - test

tests:
  stage: test
  image: ruby:3.2.2
  services:
    - postgres:15.1
  variables:
    POSTGRES_USER: rails
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: rails
    DB_USERNAME: rails
    DB_PASSWORD: rails
    DB_HOST: postgres
    DB_PORT: 5432
    RAILS_ENV: test
    DISABLE_SPRING: 1
    BUNDLE_PATH: vendor/bundle
  script:
    - gem install bundler -v 2.4.14
    - bundle install
    - bundle exec rails db:migrate
    - bundle exec rails db:create db:schema:load --trace
    - bundle exec rails test
  only:
    - tags
```

But then when I run the pipeline I get this error message:

```
$ bundle exec rails db:migrate
rails aborted!
LoadError: Could not load the 'localhost' Active Record adapter. Ensure that the adapter is spelled correctly in config/database.yml and that you've added the necessary adapter gem to your Gemfile.
```

In my config/database.yml I have set the database settings to this:

```
default: &default
  adapter: <%= ENV['DB_CONNECTION'] || 'localhost' %>
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5
  host: <%= ENV['DB_HOST'] || 'localhost' %>
  port: <%= ENV['DB_PORT'] || 5432 %>
  username: <%= ENV['DB_USERNAME'] || 'postgres' %>
  password: <%= ENV['DB_PASSWORD'] || 'postgres' %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: <%= ENV['DB_DATABASE'] || 'database' %>

test:
  <<: *default
  database: <%= ENV['DB_DATABASE'] || 'database-test' %>

production:
  <<: *default
  database: <%= ENV['DB_DATABASE'] || 'database' %>
```

When I start this project locally and then run `rails test`, my tests are executed successfully. Why is the pipeline environment ignoring my environment variables that I am trying to pass?

I also tried creating a `.env.pipeline` and added:

```
before_script:
  - cp .env.pipeline .env
```

But that results in the same error... What am I missing here?

Comment: You don't have `DB_CONNECTION` env variable specified, so it's defaulting to `localhost`. Add it in `variables` section and set it to `postgresql`. Also make sure the `pg` gem is bundled in your Gemfile's global scope or `test` group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the `adapter` settings.

```
LoadError: Could not load the 'localhost' Active Record adapter. Ensure that the adapter is spelled correctly in config/database.yml and that you've added the necessary adapter gem to your Gemfile.
```

config/database.yml:

```
default: &default
  adapter: <%= ENV['DB_CONNECTION'] || 'localhost' %> ## incorrect
  encoding: unicode
```

Change this to `postgresql` as per the [documentation](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database)

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql 
  encoding: unicode
```

Also, you seem to have a lot of `DB-*` variables that are not properly used/set, fix that as well.